# sql missing from clause

Tags: sql, postgresql

```
  select m_product.name ,c_bpartner.name  from(
  select count(m_product.name) 
  from m_product
  union
  select count(c_bpartner.name) 
  from c_bpartner
  ) as total
```

I am getting error.

Error:

> missing from-clause entry for table m_product.

Im trying to get the total number of products and bpartner in a table.
Thank you for any help.

```
 |total number of product|total number of bp|
 |     1000              |   1200           |
 |                       |                  |
```

This is what I'am trying to achieve, I'am doing this using the jasper report.

Comment: What are you trying to get as output ?? you can not access the m_product and c_bpartner tables from outside the nested SQL clause and you are doing a union on unrelated columns. SQL seems to be missing the logic.

Comment: personal advice: try to format your SQL-statements - 
have a look at [SQL style guide](http://www.sqlstyle.guide/)
 - proper formated SQL statements make trouble shooting & all futher changes easier for you and your fellows

Comment: Edit your question (or ask a new one) with sample data, desired results, and an explanation of what you want to do.  This query makes no sense.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. You need to alias and group

```
select MyCount,Name  from(
  select MyCount=count(m_product.name),Name=m_product.name 
  from m_product
  group by m_product.name
  union
  select count(c_bpartner.name) ,c_bpartner.name
  from c_bpartner
  group by c_bpartner.name
  ) as total
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to give your columns an alias, so it would be:

```
  select total.mprodName ,total.cpartName  from(
  select count(m_product.name) AS mprodName
  from m_product
  union
  select count(c_bpartner.name) AS cbpartName
  from c_bpartner
  ) as total
```

Answer (score 0):

Cause you are missing `c_bpartner` table reference in `FROM` clause. Your query is total wired .. not sure why you need that `UNION` at all cause you are not using any of the column from that `UNION` result set. You probably would just perform a `JOIN` between the table like

```
select m_product.name ,
c_bpartner.name  
from m_product
join c_bpartner on m_product.id = c_bpartner.id;
```

Comment: The reason im using union is to have two columns , one for the total number of products and the other for total number of business partners

Answer (score 0):

This statement should select each product with a count of ocurrances and do the same for bpartner.

```
      SELECT m_product.name
            ,COUNT(m_product.name)    
        FROM m_product
    GROUP BY m_product.name
UNION ALL 
      SELECT c_bpartner.name
            ,COUNT(c_bpartner.name)    
        FROM c_bpartner
    GROUP BY c_bpartner.name
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 with output as (
   select count(m_product.name) from m_product union
   select count(c_bpartner.name) from c_bpartner
 ) 
 select * from output;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select total.m_product_name ,total.c_bpartner_name  from(
  select count(m_product.name) as m_product_name,'NIL' as  c_bpartner_name
  from m_product
  union
  select 'NIL',count(c_bpartner.name) 
  from c_bpartner
  ) as total
```